# why threadpool can't run which created int the mainthread which running under the daemon way

Tags: python, threadpool

TestDaemon.py a test daemon which init a threadpool and create a task put in the threadpool,but when I run the TestDaemon.py under the daemon way,the task which in threadpool has not print log,but when I run  TestDaemon.py not under the daemon way,the task has print the log,I don't know why,so ask for help here,thx first!!!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8
import threadpool, sys, time
import logging, logging.config

from daemon import Daemon

logging.config.fileConfig(sys.path[0] + '/logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('opsagent')


class TestDaemon(Daemon):
    def __init__(self, pid):
        Daemon.__init__(self, pid)
        self.pool = threadpool.ThreadPool(5)

    def hello(self, n):
        while (True):
            time.sleep(1)
            logger.info('hello')

    def run(self):
        reqs = threadpool.makeRequests(self.hello, [1])
        logger.info(reqs)
        [self.pool.putRequest(req) for req in reqs]

        while (True):
            time.sleep(1)
            logger.info('mainThread')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pid = '/tmp/testtest.pid'
    d = TestDaemon(pid)
    logger.info('start test')
    d.start()
```

the Daemon class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8

import sys, os, time, atexit, commands
from signal import SIGTERM


class Daemon:
"""
A generic daemon class.

Usage: subclass the Daemon class and override the run() method
"""

def __init__(self, pidfile, stdin='/dev/null', stdout='/dev/null', stderr='/dev/null'):
    self.stdin = stdin
    self.stdout = stdout
    self.stderr = stderr
    self.pidfile = pidfile

def daemonize(self):
    """
    do the UNIX double-fork magic, see Stevens' "Advanced
    Programming in the UNIX Environment" for details (ISBN 0201563177)
    http://www.erlenstar.demon.co.uk/unix/faq_2.html#SEC16
    """
    try:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid > 0:
            # exit first parent
            sys.exit(0)
    except OSError, e:
        sys.stderr.write("fork #1 failed: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
        sys.exit(1)

    # decouple from parent environment
    os.chdir("/")
    os.setsid()
    os.umask(0)

    # do second fork
    try:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid > 0:
            # exit from second parent
            sys.exit(0)
    except OSError, e:
        sys.stderr.write("fork #2 failed: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
        sys.exit(1)

    # redirect standard file descriptors
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stderr.flush()
    si = file(self.stdin, 'a+')
    so = file(self.stdout, 'a+')
    se = file(self.stderr, 'a+', 0)
    os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())
    os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
    os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())

    # write pidfile
    atexit.register(self.delpid)
    pid = str(os.getpid())
    file(self.pidfile, 'w+').write("%s\n" % pid)

def delpid(self):
    os.remove(self.pidfile)

def start(self):
    """
    Start the daemon
    """
    # Check for a pidfile to see if the daemon already runs
    try:
        pf = file(self.pidfile, 'r')
        pid = int(pf.read().strip())
        pf.close()
    except:
        pid = None

    if pid:
        # 判断线程是否真的不存在
        command = 'ps -A|grep -w ' + str(pid) + '|grep -v grep'
        status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(command)
        if status == 0:
            message = "pidfile %s already exist. Daemon already running?\n"
            sys.stderr.write(message % self.pidfile)
            sys.exit(1)

    # Start the daemon
    self.daemonize()
    self.run()

def stop(self):
    """
    Stop the daemon
    """
    # Get the pid from the pidfile
    try:
        pf = file(self.pidfile, 'r')
        pid = int(pf.read().strip())
        pf.close()
    except:
        pid = None

    if not pid:
        message = "pidfile %s does not exist. Daemon not running?\n"
        sys.stderr.write(message % self.pidfile)
        return  # not an error in a restart

    # Try killing the daemon process
    try:
        while 1:
            os.kill(pid, SIGTERM)
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except OSError, err:
        err = str(err)
        if err.find("No such process") > 0:
            if os.path.exists(self.pidfile):
                os.remove(self.pidfile)
        else:
            print str(err)
            sys.exit(1)

def restart(self):
    """
    Restart the daemon
    """
    self.stop()
    self.start()

def run(self):
    """
    You should override this method when you subclass Daemon. It will be called after the process has been
    daemonized by start() or restart().
    """
```